# How to execute dynamic query using table name that is the input parameter

Tags: postgresql

I have following simple postgresql function that want to get the row count for the input table name.

```
create or replace function func_execute_query_4(table_name varchar)
returns integer as $$
declare
c integer;

begin
 execute 'select count(*) into c from '|| table_name;
 return c;
end
$$ language plpgsql;

select func_execute_query_4('emp');
```

`emp` is an already existed table, When I run the above query, an error occurs, complains that

```
doesn't execute EXECUTE of SELECT ... INTO
```

I would ask where the problem is,thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From [Execute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

> EXECUTE command-string [ INTO [STRICT] target ] [ USING expression [, ... ] ];

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.func_execute_query_4(table_name character varying)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
c integer;

begin
 execute 'select count(*)  from '|| table_name into c;
 return c;
end
$function$
;

select func_execute_query_4('cell_per');
 func_execute_query_4 
----------------------
                   73
```

The form you where using is for non-dynamic queries from here [43.5.3. Executing a Command with a Single-Row Result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW):

> SELECT select_expressions INTO [STRICT] target FROM ...;